# Javascript and HTML (yes) - OpenWeatherMap API - how to search cities and get the data from them?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to do a search engine (kind of), and am in need of help because I have some knowledge now of Javascript and HTML, but not this amount unfortunately.

This is all weather by the way, using OpenWeatherMap's free API.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name=""viewport" content=""width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My weather app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <form>
 <input type="text" id="cityName" placeholder="Enter a city name"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Get Weather Information" id="weather_data">
</form>

<div id="display_data"></div>

    <h1 id=city_name"> Please wait...</h1>
    <p id="myParagraph">Please wait...</p>
    <img id="icon" src = "" alt = "Weather icon">
    <p id="myTemp"> Please wait...</p> 
    <p id="minimum">Please wait...</p>
    <p id="maximum">Please wait...</p>


    <script src="City_Name.js"></script>
    <script src="Data.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the City_Name script:

```
    // Fetch Wweather data from API and searching for a city 

        var weatherData = document.getElementById("weather_data");
  weatherData.addEventListener('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var cityName = document.getElementById("cityName").value;
 var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+cityName+"&appid={API Key}"
 if(cityName == ""){
      alert("Enter a city name");
  }else{
  fetch(url).then(function(response){
      if(response.ok){
          return response.json();
      }else{
          throw new Error(Error);
      }
  }).then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    const html =    `
        <h2 class="text-danger text-center"><span class="text-dark">City:</span>${data.name}</h2>
        ` ;
      document.getElementById("display_data").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',html);
  }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
  });
  }
});
```

And here is the Data script:

```
    // Fetching City_Name to the script
    include('City_Name.js')
    
    // Fetch   API
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+cityName+'&appid={API Key')
    
  // Convert response string to json object
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {

    // Display whole API response in browser console (take a look at it!)
    console.log(response);


    // Copy one element of response to our HTML paragraph
    document.getElementById("myParagraph").innerHTML ="The weather is: " + response.weather[0].description;
    document.getElementById("icon").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + response.weather[0].icon + "@2x.png";
    document.getElementById("myTemp").innerHTML = "The temperature is: " + response.main.temp + " °C";
    document.getElementById("minimum").innerHTML = "The minimum temperature should be: " + response.main.temp_min;
    document.getElementById("maximum").innerHTML = "The minimum temperature should be: " + response.main.temp_max;
    
  })
  .catch(err => {
    
    // Display errors in console
    console.log(err);
});
```

The Data.js used to work fine with one city, like `fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Tokyo&appid={API  Key}')`, but now it doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what does `Fetching City_Name to the script` and `include('City_Name.js')` mean? why are you fetching the data in both city_name and data scripts? Where is `cityName` defined in the Data script?

Comment: I use two seperate scripts because they aren't working together in one script. ```include(City_Name')``` is basically putting the script in I thinkk.

Comment: not in any javascript I've ever seen - have you checked the browser developer console for errors?

Comment: Yes, I did, thoroughly.

Comment: yet `include('City_Name.js')` doesn't throw an error - I may be having a "senior moment" - because `include` is not (standard) javascript - but still, how would `cityName` be defined in data script? since it's only declared inside a click handler

Comment: Because it is asking for the ```cityName``` in the Data script, so I thought it needed to be in there too, or am I wrong?

Comment: cityName variable needs to exist ... what is its value? use console.log to find out

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, you're going to need to have a single Javascript file for this to work. The `City_Name.js`.

After this line of code,  `document.getElementById("display_data").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',html);`,  you don't need to have `response.whateveritis`. You're going to need `data.whateveritis`.

I hope that this answer will suit everyone's needs.

Thanks!

P.S.
Yes, I'm answering my own question.